# Facing 401 Bad Credentials error on applying terraform Apply while using Github Actions to create a Github repo using Terraform

Tags: terraform, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to create a Github repository using terraform and Github Actions. I am using push as trigger for the workflow. Each time I push I am facing this error on terraform apply:

```
[Error: POST https://api.github.com/user/repos: 401 Bad credentials \[\]
    │ 
    │   with github_repository.github-repo-1,
    │   on main.tf line 5, in resource "github_repository" "github-repo-1":
    │    5: resource github_repository github-repo-1 {][1]
```

0

This is the provider configuration (provider.tf).

```
terraform {
      required_providers {
        github = {
          source  = "integrations/github"
          version = "~> 4.0"
        }
      }
    }
    provider "github" {
        token = var.Token
        owner = var.Owner
    }
```

What are the different ways to solve this error?

Comment: Does it work on your local machine? If so do you use same github api token on your pc and in github actions?

Comment: @ravenwing It was not working on local machine as well. It was showing this error on terraform apply. I have used the same API token.

Comment: Great, then we know it has nothing to do with github-actions. Now there are two problems that can be there (that I can think of): wrong permissions for token and wrong setup of provider.

To check first one select all checkboxes in tokens permission (just for single test). If it will pass then try to locate what exact permissions you need. If it won't - please provide your provider configuration (without api token of course ;) )

Comment: I have selected all checkboxes in the token permissions for a single test but still it was showing the same error.

Comment: @ravenwing I have added the provider configuration. What are the possible ways to solve this error?

Comment: Try to use curl with same token. And if it fails post result. But if it pass - than provider is configured with other variables probably.

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-for-the-authenticated-user